# Compare two equations in Maple

Tags: maple

Do any of you know how to compare alternative forms of equations in maple? 
No matter of what maple says false when I try to compare my two equations but I know they are the same.

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} - \frac{3}{2}x^{2} + 100x\\
g(x) &= x\left(100-\frac{3}{2}x\right) + \frac{1}{2}x^{2}\sin(60^{\circ})
\end{align*}

I've tried

```
is(f(x)=g(x))
evalb(f(x)=g(x))
```

so far so good, but both report false while I know they are the same equations and wolfrom also reports true.

Comment: Are those supposed to be $$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} - \frac{3}{2}x^{2} + 100x,\quad g(x) = x\left(100-\frac{3}{2}x\right) + \frac{1}{2}xx\sin(60^{\circ})\ ?$$

Comment: yes they are. How did you write the equations that way? latex => png ?

Comment: In $f (x) $ you missed the factor $x*x $ just after $\sqrt {3} $.

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes Math SE supports [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Maple uses [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), not degrees. Hence
$$60^\circ = \frac{1}{3} \pi\,\text{ rad}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

replace $\sin (60) $ by $\sin (\frac \pi 3) $

and

add $x*x $ after $\sqrt {3} $ in the expression of $f (x) $ and try

> simplify $ (f (x)-g (x));$

you should get $0$.

Comment: Sadly, I didn't

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes replace 60 by pi/3.

Comment: Gonna try that but I've all ready tried sqrt(4)/3 which is the same as sin(60)

Comment: @DanielGuldbergAaes No no it is \sqrt {3}/2 not the inverse.

Comment: So I did as you said and I still don't get 0 as a result

Comment: You *shouldn't* get 0 as a result, because the difference is *not* zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to get the difference to be zero because your both equations/functions are not the same.

```
restart:
f:=(x)->sqrt(3)/4-3/2*x^2+100*x;
g:=(x)->x*(100-3/2*x)+1/2*x^2*sin(60);
f(x)-g(x);
evalf(simplify(%));
```

> 0.1524053106 $x^2$ + 0.4330127020