# How do I compare two expressions in Maple to see if they’re equivalent?

Tags: maple

I have to compare two expressions as an assignment but the professor didn’t explain how to do it (I doubt he actually knows how to do the stuff he asks us to do). The two expression pairs in question:

```
tg(x) + tg(y) = (sin(x+y))/cos(x)*cos(y)

arcsin(x) + arcsin(y) = pi/2
```

Now I know these are true, but whenever I use `evalb` or `is` I invariably get `false`. I tried many different things but none of them work and I’ve searched the internet for help but I didn’t find anything useful. The most similar thing to mine was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273822/compare-two-equations-in-maple) but I tried the solution and it didn’t work. Please help, I’m losing my sanity.

Answer (score 3):

You may have mistyped `tg(...)` when you actually mean `tan(...)`, where `tan` is the name of a trigonometric function in Maple.

In that case you seem to be missing brackets in the right hand side of the first equation. Note the difference in the output that the extra pair of brackets makes:

```
tan(x) + tan(y) = (sin(x+y))/cos(x)*cos(y);

                     sin(x + y) cos(y)
   tan(x) + tan(y) = -----------------
                          cos(x)


tan(x) + tan(y) = (sin(x+y))/(cos(x)*cos(y));

                      sin(x + y)
   tan(x) + tan(y) = -------------
                     cos(x) cos(y)
```

And now,

```
eq1 := tan(x) + tan(y) = (sin(x+y))/(cos(x)*cos(y)):

is(eq1);

             true
```

For your second equation, note that the well-known constant is spelled `Pi` in Maple. The lowercase name `pi` has no special meaning to Maple.

You might try the `solve` command, as one way to reformulate the implied relationship between `x` and `y`. Eg,

```
 eq2 := arcsin(x) + arcsin(y) = Pi/2:

 solve(eq2);

                    2     1/2
     {x = x, y = (-x  + 1)   }
```

This forum is for mathematics, and questions about Maple syntax and programming are better suited to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) or [www.mapleprimes.com](https://www.mapleprimes.com) (the Maplesoft user community).

[edit] You provided a revision to your second equation in a comment to another answer.You gave it as,

```
eq2 := arcsin(x) + arccos(x) = Pi/2:
```

Note the conversion,

```
convert(arcsin(x), arccos);

     1/2*Pi - arccos(x)
```

And so these all work here.

```
convert((lhs-rhs)(eq2),ln);

           0

convert((lhs-rhs)(eq2),arcsin);

           0

convert((lhs-rhs)(eq2),arccos);

           0
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, I got confused about `tg` and `tan`, partly because by professor himself wrote `tg` in the assignment, and partly because I always assumed the former to be more common, even though I myself use `tan`. Also thanks for advice, I will post on Maple Primes next time.

Comment: I added something for your revised second equation.

Answer (score 2):

For the first equation, this worked:

[image]

For the second equation, it appears that the same method didn't simplify it to 0 automatically. Converting arcsin() to arccos() solved the problem:

[image]

Comment: OK, I was a dumbass, sorry. The second equation is actually `arcsin (x) + arccos (x) = Pi/2`, not what I wrote. I wrote that correctly in Maple but when i was writing this question I was in the midst of a mental breakdown. Thanks for answering and taking your time.

Comment: edited my question based on the correct equation